# Pen input with Huion 1060 plus lags in Krita

Tags: windows-10, graphics-tablet

I have downloaded [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) and I am trying to use it with the [Huion New 1060 Plus](https://www.huion.com/de/pen_tablet/Huion/NEW_1060PLUS.html) pen input tablet.

However, the input lags so much / has such a high delay that Krita only draws a few dots when I am actually writing a complete word.

What can I do?

I have already tried:

- using less pixels (DIN A4 300 ppi instead of DIN A4 600 ppi)
- updating the [1060 Plus drivers](https://www.huion.com/de/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=lists&catid=16&down_title2=NEW%201060PLUS(8192)) to the latest version
- change performance settings in Krita [as suggested on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/krita/comments/8qd7og/krita_lag_fix/)

I am using Krita 4.2.9, Windows 10 x64 1909 Build 18363.836 and Huion drivers 14.8.90.1126.

For some reason, the Huion Tablet App says "Device not connected", although the pen works e.g. in Powerpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Krita, you can change the input mode from *WinTab* to the older *Windows Ink* input mode. This fixed the lags for me. You find this option in tablet settings, one item below the performance settings.

[image: Screenshot of Krita tablet input API]

Don't forget that you need to restart Krita after this change.